# Getting Errors and Warning to show In Eclipse via Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'm using the m2eclipse plugin for eclipse to build my project, but I miss having the errors and warning of my build show up in the Problems tab.  I use a maven project builder to build my project and don't use the default java builder in eclipse.  I would really love a way to get all the errors and warnings that I can see when editing a file to show up in the problems tab, and I would like this tab to show problems for my whole project.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you have `m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)` installed? Installing it helped me get some maven build error messages in the 'Error Log' view.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong. Per default, m2eclipse activates the java builder and shows errors / warnings.

Did you by any chance check out a multi-module maven project and convert it to a single eclipse project? If yes, you need to `Import -> Existing Maven Projects` and select the projects underneath the root.

Otherwise, you may just have to right-click the project and select `Maven -> update Project Configuration`.

If neither of these help, please provide more info.

Comment: Neither of these helped, and I'm not sure what other info to give.

Comment: Well, post the pom.xml (perhaps to pastebin) or better yet, post the project or a representative part of it as a zip file on a public server and I'll have a look if I can find the problem.

Comment: One more thing: what's the project packaging?